# Fetching JSON Data Error

Tags: java, php, android, json

this is jSon Data File from where i want to fetch the data but there is following -

```
error: 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887): org.json.JSONException: No value for     
vehicle_type 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887):    at  
 org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)

 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887):    at   
 org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887):    at   
 com.example.capo.ui.MyCarActivity.returnjson(MyCarActivity.java:124)
 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887):    at      
 com.example.capo.net.JSONPostRequest.onPostExecute(JSONPostRequest.java:63)
 05-28 12:42:41.691: W/System.err(2887):    at     
 com.example.capo.net.JSONPostRequest.onPostExecute(JSONPostRequest.java:1)
```

`JSON` code:

```
{"status":"1","records":[{"vehicle_company":"jande","vehicle_type":"751","vehicle_color":"Black","vehicle_rc":"harry1234","vehicle_capacity":"6"}],"message":"selected
> Data"}
```

The code to parse the `JSON`:

```
 //...
    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        // jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;

}
//...
```

The `POJO` `Java` class to map the object to:
     public class MyCar {

```
public String                                                       

 vehicle_type,vehicle_company,vehicle_color,vehicle_rc,vehicle_capacity;



  public String getVehicle_type() {
     return vehicle_type;
 }

 public void setVehicle_type(String vehicle_type) {
     this.vehicle_type = vehicle_type;
 }
 public String getVehicle_company() {
     return vehicle_company;
 }

 public void setVehicle_company(String vehicle_company) {
     this.vehicle_company = vehicle_company;
 }

 public String getVehicle_color() {
    return vehicle_color;
 }

 public void setVehicle_color(String vehicle_color) {
     this.vehicle_color = vehicle_color;
 }

 public String getVehicle_rc() {
     return vehicle_rc;
}

public void setVehicle_rc(String vehicle_rc) {
     this.vehicle_rc = vehicle_rc;
 }

 public String getVehicle_capacity() {
     return vehicle_capacity;
 }

public void setVehicle_capacity(String vehicle_capacity) {
    this.vehicle_capacity = vehicle_capacity;
 }

}
```

Comment: too long post only the parsing code

Comment: Sir help me to solve this error

Comment: your JSON is invalid. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: post the relevant parsing code the rest is not required the stacktrace tells your json parsing is wrong and do check if json is valid as others suggested

Comment: yes i have posted you can see above

Comment: Did not get answer Yet

Comment: Raghunandan please help me :: 06-03 05:41:43.143: E/==>(1562): Failed to download file
06-03 05:41:43.143: E/JSON Parser(1562): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-03 05:41:43.193: I/System.out(1562): 1
06-03 05:41:43.193: W/System.err(1562): org.json.JSONException: No value for vehicle_type
06-03 05:41:43.203: W/System.err(1562):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
06-03 05:41:43.203: W/System.err(1562):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
06-03 05:41:43.203: W/System.err(1562

Answer (score 1):

Go to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and parse it and you will see that your `JSON` has an invalid syntax at records (missing '":'):

Yours:

```
   {
    "status": "1",
    "records[
        {
            "vehicle_company": "jande",
            "vehicle_type": "751",
            "vehicle_color": "Black",
            "vehicle_rc": "harry1234",
            "vehicle_capacity": "6"
        }
    ],
    "message": "selectedData"
   }
```

Correct:

```
 {
    "status": "1",
    "records": [
        {
            "vehicle_company": "jande",
            "vehicle_type": "751",
            "vehicle_color": "Black",
            "vehicle_rc": "harry1234",
            "vehicle_capacity": "6"
        }
    ],
    "message": "selectedData"
}
```

Comment: No before its i have used Json already just like this  , but i got error only from this

Comment: sorry i uploaded wrong json file .. now i uploaded correct

Answer (score 0):

Your json is wrong at result array,It will be like:

```
"result":
```

Comment: Did  not get answer yet

Comment: your json data is not correct dude,,ask from server guy who had written this web service.

Answer (score 0):

The json you posted (I trust is not a copy and paste error) is wrong:

{"status":"1","**records**[{"vehicle_company":"jande","vehicle_type":"751","vehicle_color":"Black","vehicle_rc":"harry1234","vehicle_capacity":"6"}],"message":"selected Data"}

should be (formatted):

```
 {
  "status":"1",
  "records":[
    {
     "vehicle_company":"jande",
     "vehicle_type":"751",
     "vehicle_color":"Black",
     "vehicle_rc":"harry1234",
     "vehicle_capacity":"6"
  }
  ],
  "message":"selected Data"
}
```

Comment: sorry i uploaded wrong json file .. now i uploaded correct and same error exits again

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I would advise you to dump the objects contained in the array "records" and the father object then:

```
jObj = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
Log.v("JSON Parser", "jObj:"+jObj);
Log.v("JSON Parser", "array:"+jObj.getJSONArray("records"));
JSONObject elem = jObj.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(0);
Log.v("JSON Parser", "obj:"+elem);
```

And see what shows up...

Comment: same error :    05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554): org.json.JSONException: No value for vehicle_type
05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554):  at com.example.capo.ui.MyCarActivity.returnjson(MyCarActivity.java:124)
05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554):  at com.example.capo.net.JSONPostRequest.onPostExecute(JSONPostRequest.java:63)
05-28 13:52:51.678: W/System.err(1554):

Comment: the line 
     Log.v("JSON Parser", "jObj:"+jObj);
Cannot fail tho.... shall dump the jObj as it is..

Comment: bro i did just like you told , but nothing happen without showing some entered data or the above error